Someone is sending spam email through my Exchange Server and don't know how
I am running Exchange Server 2019 15.2. Someone is sending spam through it. I have made sure that the 'Default Frontend' receive connector does not allow anonymous connections, but somehow that isn't working and I don't know what else to look at. When I look at the queue, I can still see messages waiting to go out like this (notice the the from address is blank):
Identity: Email2\347358\105106439667717 
Subject: Undeliverable: Discover Our Exclusive Luxury Watches. Shop Now For Only $250 
Internet Message ID: c9947c19-c8c6-43bf-abf0-80d534a01442@xxxxxxxxxxxx 
From Address: <> 
Status: Ready 
Size (KB): 11 
Message Source Name: DSN 
Source IP: 255.255.255.255 
SCL: -1 
Date Received: 12/24/2024 4:15:32 AM 
Expiration Time: 12/26/2024 4:15:32 AM 
Last Error: 
Queue ID: Email2\347358 
Recipients: ukyshcppmspunk@tmc-group.net;2;2;[{LED=};{MSG=};{FQDN=};{IP=};{LRT=}];0;CN=Outbound to Internet,CN=Connections,CN=Exchange Routing Group (DWBGZMFD01QNBJR),CN=Routing Groups,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=ChartMeds,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=internal,DC=xxxxxxxxxx,DC=com;0

How can I troubleshoot this?

I have made sure that the 'Default Frontend' receive connector does not allow anonymous connections how exactly are you receiving messages, then? You should not allow anonymous relay, but anonymous connections are how every mail server in the world receives emails...

This message is not spam, but backscatter; bounce messages a.k.a. Non-Delivery Reports (NDR) sent by your server to the envelope sender the original spam claimed the message was from.
The signs this is a bounce:

From Address: <>. Bounces have an empty envelope sender to avoid loops.
Subject: Undeliverable: prefix is an indirect hint.
Message Source Name: DSN says it directly; DSN is an abbrevation for Delivery Service Notification.

You need to configure your mail server to connection-stage reject messages failing SPF & DMARC checks instead of generating bounces.

Thank you, what is in the message that shows it is a 'backscatter'?

I have added an explanation to that to my answer.
